# Is there a visual modeller which supports opennetcf.orm which can also map existing databases?

Tags: sql-server, orm, sql-server-ce, opennetcf

With OpennetCf.ORM I can define entities and their relationships in C# classes, is there a way to create these entities and relationships using a more visual modeller, perhaps one which can also map existing Microsoft SQL tables?

Comment: There is a command line utility to generate mappings form an existing db

Comment: @ErikEJ any idea where I can get it? Tried doing a google search but had no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the EntityGenerator tool that is part of the release: http://orm.codeplex.com/releases/view/82434